# what better string + string or string + char?

Tags: c#, string, char

I have

```cs
    String Spaces = "";
```

and cycle. What better in the terms of performance and code style?
`Spaces += ' ';` or `Spaces += " "`?

Comment: If you add space in a *loop* (and that's why you have performance problems) try `StringBuilder` and `Append`

Comment: From my testing, both compile to the same IL. The compiler converts them both to strings. If you're trying to convert a list of stuff to a string, you might want to use `string.Join(" ", list)`.

Comment: Is initializing StringBuilder take more time than String? And also, I need to return String. Is it rational to use StringBuilder in that case (or I'll lose more time on converting and initializing)?

Comment: You're executing a loop to create a `string` with a certain number of space characters? Do you know how many iterations of this loop you're going to execute?

Comment: @Титан: could you provide more [relevant] code please? Where do you have performance problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create an instance of `string` with a specific character repeated a specific number of times, then you don't need a loop at all. [There is a constructor for that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_String__ctor_System_Char_System_Int32_).

In terms of performance, I used the following simple benchmark to find that the constructor gives you the best performance.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace SpaceStringCreationBench
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         int length = 100000;
         var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
         BuildByAppendingString(length);
         watch.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine($"BuildByAppendingString: {watch.Elapsed}");

         watch.Restart();
         BuildByAppendingChar(length);
         watch.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine($"BuildByAppendingChar: {watch.Elapsed}");

         watch.Restart();
         BuildWithStringBuilder(length);
         watch.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine($"BuildWithStringBuilder: {watch.Elapsed}");

         watch.Restart();
         BuildWithCtor(length);
         watch.Stop();
         Console.WriteLine($"BuildWithCtor: {watch.Elapsed}");
      }

      static string BuildByAppendingString(int length)
      {
         string value = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
         {
            value += " ";
         }
         return value;
      }

      static string BuildByAppendingChar(int length)
      {
         string value = "";
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
         {
            value += ' ';
         }
         return value;
      }

      static string BuildWithStringBuilder(int length)
      {
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
         for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
         {
            sb.Append(" ");
         }
         return sb.ToString();
      }

      static string BuildWithCtor(int length)
      {
         return new string(' ', length);
      }
   }
}

/*
Output:
BuildByAppendingString: 00:00:01.0523856
BuildByAppendingChar: 00:00:01.0380273
BuildWithStringBuilder: 00:00:00.0013483
BuildWithCtor: 00:00:00.0001228
*/
```

As for style, well... I reckon that you'll get different answers from different people but for something like this I'd argue that the constructor is the way to go.

All of this is assuming that the length of the `string` you're generating varies. If you just need the same number of spaces every time you run this process and its a reasonably small number, just instantiate that `string`. For example, if you all you need is a `string` with five spaces just do this:

`string spaces = "     ";`